# Split a list into two lists upon seeing a specific element

Tags: python, list, split

Suppose I have a list in Python. Whenever I encounter `'a'` in the list, I should break the list into two lists and put the `'a'` either at the end of the first list or the start of the second. How do I keep doing this until I have several lists, each with at most one occurrence of `'a'`?

Here is my attempt. It works but is pretty ugly.

```
input_list = [0, 1, 'a', 'b', 'c', 2]
partitioned_list = []
temp_list =[]
for item in input_list:
     temp_list.append(item)
     if item == 'a':
         partitioned_list.append(temp_list)
         temp_list = []
partitioned_list.append(temp_list)
```

I get as output `[[0, 1, 'a'],['b', 'c', 2]]` for the `input_list` given above.

Comment: too much to ask. show the code you tried also include sample input and expected output in your post

Comment: Okay, will do shortly. Thank you!

Comment: So for an empty input list, you want `[[]]` instead of `[]`?

Comment: @superbrain, I actually didn't think about it but I will never have an empty list so this is okay. Ideally, it would be nicer to have `[]` instead of `[[]]`. About your comment below, that's a good point. My code gives me an annoying empty list which I could do without

Comment: And for `[0, 1, 'a']` you want `[[0, 1, 'a'], []]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that I understood what you wanted:

```
input_list = [0, 1, 'a', 'b', 'c', 2, 'a', 21, 'c', 'a', 'a','b','a']
partitioned_lists = []
start = 0
for index, item in enumerate(input_list):
    if item == 'a':
        partitioned_lists.append(input_list[start:index+1])
        start = index + 1
    
if start != len(input_list):
    partitioned_lists.append(input_list[start:])
print(partitioned_lists)
```